# python pandas filter by part of rows existing in a list

Tags: python, pandas

i have this DataFrame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : [data1|context1, data2|context2, data3|context3, data4|context4]})
```

resulting:

```
   A
0  data1|context1
1  data2|context2
2  data3|context3
3  data4|context4
```

i also have this list:

```
items = ['data1', 'data3']
```

I want to get the Dataframe rows which do not have their left part of |  in the list. How do i filter only by the left part of each row? I know only how to filter by the entire row, but not by part of it.

This should be the result:

```
   A
0  data2|context2
1  data4|context4
```

Edit: obtining this result with pandas would be more efficient than getting the values in a list comprehensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean mask based on [match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html):

```
import pandas as pd

items = ['data1', 'data3']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['data1|context1', 'data2|context2', 'data3|context3', 'data4|context4']})

mask = df.A.str.match('^(?!{})'.format('|'.join(items)))
result = df[mask]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
                A
1  data2|context2
3  data4|context4
```

The statement `'^(?!{})'.format('|'.join(items))` becomes `^(?!data1|data3)` that means not start with neither `'data1'` nor `'data3'`. If you prefer a one-liner you can do:

```
result = df.loc[df.A.str.match('^(?!{})'.format('|'.join(items)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
df.loc[df['A'].str.split('|').apply(lambda x: x[0] not in items )]
```

Output

```
                A
1  data2|context2
3  data4|context4
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
print(df.loc[~df.A.str.extract(r'([^|]+)').isin(items)[0]].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
                A
0  data2|context2
1  data4|context4
```